# No change in joint positions

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, joy-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I am trying to control my robot arm through xbox 360 controller and for the same I have visualized the arm in rviz and I have a small trial code in python for controlling the motion of joints. It's a 5 DOF arm.

After connecting the controller, I first launch the `demo.launch` file and then `rosrun joy joy_node` followed by the python code for controlling the motion of the joints. When I run the python code, the joint values are all 0 at the beginning. But, as I press the controller buttons, there is no change in the arm's pose.

Could anyone guide me as to where am I doing the mistake? I also would like to know how can I visualize the joint movements, that I give through my controller, in rviz?

The python code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import copy
import rospy
import moveit_commander
import moveit_msgs.msg
import geometry_msgs.msg
from sensor_msgs.msg import *

    def callback(data):
        
        robot = moveit_commander.RobotCommander()
        
        #scene = moveit_commander.PlanningSceneInterface()
        
        group1 = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("igus_planning")
        end_effector_link =  group1.get_end_effector_link()
        
        display_trajectory_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/move_group/display_planned_path',
                  moveit_msgs.msg.DisplayTrajectory,queue_size=50)
        
        
      
        print "============ Waiting for RVIZ..."
        #rospy.sleep(1)
        print "============ Reference frame: %s" % group1.get_planning_frame()
        print "============ End effector: %s" % group1.get_end_effector_link()
        print "============ Robot Groups: %s" %robot.get_group_names()
        
        print "============ Printing robot state"
        print robot.get_current_state()
        print "=============="
        #print end_effector_link
        
        print "============ current pose..."
        print group1.get_current_pose()
        
        
        group1_variable_values = group1.get_current_joint_values()

        ###################   0 and 6   ########################
        while data.buttons[0]==1:
            if (data.axes[6]==1):
                if (group1_variable_values[0] == 3.1): 
                    print "Limit reached joint 1"
                else:
                    print "changing joint 1"
                group1_variable_values[0] += 0.1
            if (data.axes[6]==-1):
                if (group1_variable_values[0] == -3.1): 
                    print "Limit reached joint 1"
                else:
                    print "changing joint 1"
                group1_variable_values[0] -= 0.1
        
        group1.set_joint_value_target(group1_variable_values)
        
        plan2 = group1.plan()
        print group1.get_planning_time()
        print "plan complete"
    
    def move_group_python_interface():
        moveit_commander.roscpp_initialize(sys.argv)
        rospy.init_node('move_group_python_interface', anonymous=True)
        rospy.Subscriber("joy", Joy, callback)
        rospy.spin()
    
    
    if __name__=='__main__':
        try:
            move_group_python_interface()
        except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
            pass
```

The output that I am getting even after pressing the controller buttons are:

```
[ INFO] [1525969960.203313336]: Ready to take commands for planning group igus1.
============ Waiting for RVIZ...
============ Reference frame: /world
============ End effector: ee_link
============ Robot Groups: ['igus1']
============ Printing robot state
joint_state: 
  header: 
    seq: 0
    stamp: 
      secs: 0
      nsecs:         0
    frame_id: "/world"
  name: [j1, j2, j3, j4, ee_joint]
  position: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
  velocity: []
  effort: []
multi_dof_joint_state: 
  header: 
    seq: 0
    stamp: 
      secs: 0
      nsecs:         0
    frame_id: "/world"
  joint_names: []
  transforms: []
  twist: []
  wrench: []
attached_collision_objects: []
is_diff: False
==============
5.0
plan complete
[ INFO] [1525969961.417759417]: Ready to take commands for planning group igus1.
============ Waiting for RVIZ...
============ Reference frame: /world
============ End effector: ee_link
============ Robot Groups: ['igus1']
============ Printing robot state
joint_state: 
  header: 
    seq: 0
    stamp: 
      secs: 0
      nsecs:         0
    frame_id: "/world"
  name: [j1, j2, j3, j4, ee_joint]
  position: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
  velocity: []
  effort: []
multi_dof_joint_state: 
  header: 
    seq: 0
    stamp: 
      secs: 0
      nsecs:         0
    frame_id: "/world"
  joint_names: []
  transforms: []
  twist: []
  wrench: []
attached_collision_objects: []
is_diff: False
==============
5.0
plan complete
```

and in the `demo.launch` terminal, I am getting the following output:

```
[ INFO] [1525970703.485868157]: Planning request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning pipeline.
Debug:   Starting goal sampling thread
Debug:   Waiting for space information to be set up before the sampling thread can begin computation...
[ INFO] [1525970703.488563842]: Planner configuration 'igus1' will use planner 'geometric::RRTConnect'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.
Debug:   RRTConnect: Planner range detected to be 4.240270
Info:    RRTConnect: Starting planning with 1 states already in datastructure
Debug:   RRTConnect: Waiting for goal region samples ...
Debug:   Beginning sampling thread computation
Debug:   Stopped goal sampling thread after 10 sampling attempts
Debug:   RRTConnect: Waited 0.010157 seconds for the first goal sample.
Info:    RRTConnect: Created 4 states (2 start + 2 goal)
Info:    Solution found in 0.011676 seconds
Info:    SimpleSetup: Path simplification took 0.000092 seconds and changed from 3 to 2 states
[ INFO] [1525970704.785523323]: Planning request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning pipeline.
Debug:   Starting goal sampling thread
Debug:   Waiting for space information to be set up before the sampling thread can begin computation...
[ INFO] [1525970704.786152331]: Planner configuration 'igus1' will use planner 'geometric::RRTConnect'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.
Debug:   RRTConnect: Planner range detected to be 4.240270
Info:    RRTConnect: Starting planning with 1 states already in datastructure
Debug:   RRTConnect: Waiting for goal region samples ...
Debug:   Beginning sampling thread computation
Debug:   Stopped goal sampling thread after 10 sampling attempts
Debug:   RRTConnect: Waited 0.010122 seconds for the first goal sample.
Info:    RRTConnect: Created 4 states (2 start + 2 goal)
Info:    Solution found in 0.011302 seconds
Info:    SimpleSetup: Path simplification took 0.000702 seconds and changed from 3 to 17 states
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290832/no-change-in-joint-positions/) by [Kashyap.m94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33183/kashyap.m94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2018-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your code appears to plan a path to the new position but it never executes it.

If you call `group1.execute()` or use `planAndExecute()` then it should move your virtual arm.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kashyap.m94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33183/kashyap.m94/) on 2018-05-11**:
Thanks for the help. Now the problem that I am having is that the joint positions are constantly changing right from the moment I launch the python code even if I am not giving the input through the controller. Also, the change in position is not being visualized in rviz. Any suggestions ?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-05-11**:
You need to indent the `group1_variable_values[0] += 0.1` and `group1_variable_values[0] -= 0.1` lines one more time. They are currently outside of the if .. else block.

**Comment by [Kashyap.m94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33183/kashyap.m94/) on 2018-05-11**:
That was a silly error while editing it online. My bad.

But still it's not changing anything. I am adding the terminal output below.

What I feel is that the code isn't entering into the `while` statement in the code

**Comment by [Kashyap.m94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33183/kashyap.m94/) on 2018-05-11**:
I also checked it by changing the values as `group1_variable_values[0] += 10` and `group1_variable_values[0] -= 10` , still no change

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-05-11**:
Ahh yes the while loop is the problem, it's entering it Okay, but it's never leaving it! It should be an IF statement.
The while loop is testing the value of the button press at that time, so if it's 1 it will always be 1 because it's not updated with new messages from the controller.

**Comment by [Kashyap.m94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33183/kashyap.m94/) on 2018-05-11**:
The Status tab under the MotionPlanning tab in Rviz, reads 'Changed goal state', but somehow it's not being visualized on the bot in rviz. And despite changing the while loop to the if statement, I don't see any much of a difference

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-05-11**:
A couple of questions. Do you have the execute call in your new code?
Can you print out the values of `group1_variable_values` before and after processing the buttons and check the angles are being changed.

**Comment by [Kashyap.m94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33183/kashyap.m94/) on 2018-05-11**:
Yep, I have added the execute call in my code and the `group1_variable_values` are being displayed through `get_current_state` and there isn't a difference between the joint values before and after pressing the button.

**Comment by [Kashyap.m94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33183/kashyap.m94/) on 2018-05-11**:
I am also printing the position and orientation through `get_current_pose`, and both these values remain the same even though the joint values are changing continuously.

**Comment by [Kashyap.m94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33183/kashyap.m94/) on 2018-05-11**:
Do you think it has something to do with the selection of reference frame in rviz? I have a drop down list with , base_link and world as options (other options are ee_link, l1, l2, l3, l4).

Also, should I update my Start state before i give instructions from the controller?